# Excel export cell background color

Tags: excel, formatting, jasper-reports

I am using *iReport 5.6* and when I set conditional formatting for cells in a table preview in *iReport* works ok

When I save as xls document the table is shown the cells are colored and values are in the cells but they (values) are not displayed. If I set cell color to normal I can  see the values. Any ideas how to fix it. Either in Excel or iReport (preferably)?

my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_tabelegrafi" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.4641000000000006"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="92"/>
    <style name="table" lineSpacing="Single">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF" lineSpacing="Single">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF" lineSpacing="Single">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF" lineSpacing="Single">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="barva_rdeca" mode="Transparent" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" lineSpacing="Single" pattern="">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{count} > 100]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FF0000" fill="Solid" lineSpacing="Single"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{count} <= 100]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#00CC33" fill="Solid" lineSpacing="Single"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 2">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select
    o_teacher,
    o_class,
    o_location,
    count(*)
     from outputs_txt
     where o_date between  '2014-05-30' and '2014-06-30' and o_class != '' and o_location is not null
 group by o_teacher, o_class,o_location
order by  o_class,o_teacher
limit 10]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="o_teacher" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="o_class" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="o_location" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Graf">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select
    o_teacher,
    o_class,
    o_location,
    count(*)
 from outputs_txt
 where o_date between  '2014-05-30' and '2014-06-30' and o_class != '' and o_location is not null
 and o_location IN ('tel1','tel2', 'tel3')
     group by o_teacher, o_class,o_location
order by  o_class,o_teacher
limit 10]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="o_teacher" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="o_class" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="o_location" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select
    o_teacher,
    o_class,
    o_location,
    count(*)
 from outputs_txt
 where o_date between  '2014-05-30' and '2014-06-30' and o_class != '' and o_location is not null
     group by o_teacher, o_class,o_location
    order by  o_class,o_teacher
limit 10]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="o_teacher" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="o_class" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="o_location" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="154" y="0" width="234" height="38"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[TESTNI REPORT TABEL IN GRAFOV]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="287" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="barva_rdeca" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="118"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 2">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[o_teacher]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{o_teacher}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[o_class]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{o_class}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[o_location]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{o_location}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90">
                        <jr:columnHeader style="table_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                                <textElement lineSpacing="Single"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[count]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement style="barva_rdeca" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single" markup="none"/>
                                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <bar3DChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="141" width="555" height="146"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="Graf">
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{o_location}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{o_teacher}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <bar3DPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </bar3DPlot>
            </bar3DChart>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

[image: my result in excel]

Comment: Please share a report and data to reproduce or at least a sample result.

Comment: i have added xml and picture of excel

Comment: *When I save as xls document* - where do you do that? From an Excel instance started by the previewer? I had tried but I always got readable numbers in that column. (I had to change the datasources, though, because I obviously don't have your DB as backend.)

Comment: i run preview and save-->one sheet xls. values are in cells but they are not seen. also if i set an excell formula to reference the field the value is again not shown. lol i guess :-)

Comment: Ah, ok, I see, and I could reproduce that even though I'm still on iReport 4.5.1. Have you tried selecting XLS or XSLX preview from the `preview` menu and refreshing/re-running the preview generation? That creates a xls(x) parallel to the preview, and in my case numbers in that xls(x) are visible.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was that after export I selected the cells in Excel and changed type to Numeric or smth other then custom.

Comment: It just says custom. I tried to change to double, integer, etc in ireport but it was always the same in excel (custom)